# Apache Tika - Parsing MS Word - Avoid embedded documents

Tags: apache-tika

I have to handle MS Office files where multiple other files(word, excel, pdf, ...) might have been embedded by the authors, but i  only want to parse the content of the parent document.

Is it possible to configure Tika that way?

Comment: Apache Tika by default ignores embedded resources, you have to explicitly tell it that you want to recurse or extract embedded stuff. So, just use it as standard and you're set!

Comment: Are you really sure? How would a configuraiton file for that look like?

Comment: I am really really sure! It all depends on how you call Tika - the App? Tika facade? AutoDetectParser? Tika Server? Other?